# Can I use google analytics funnel to track signup process

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to create a funnel of the signup process (i.e. how many users bail out at each step).

However the numbers don't match up with the site statistics. I think the funnel is session based and not unique users based. And it also seems that a user can be counted multiple times.

What is the suggested way to get a funnel that simply tells me how many of the distinct users bail out at which step?

Comment: I'm sure there's a more exact way to do it, but if example.com/signup has 20 visitors, example.com/signupstep has 10 visitors and example.com/signupcomplete has 5 visitors, you can see that 10 people went to the signup step but only 5 people completed the process.

Comment: I"m not sure signup lends itself very well to funnels.   It usually involves a "confirm email" step outside the browser.

Answer (score 1):

### Different data

Google Analytics goals [are tracked one per session](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2679221?hl=en). If a visitor use the signup form twice in the same session, Analytics will only count one conversion. Also, in order to get all signups you should [track non-javascript visits](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-non-javascript-visits-google-analytics/).

That could explain the differences with the real registered users.

### Creating a funnel

Make sure the final goal is tracked only after a user is registered and it's not public (no one can't convert without signing up).

In order to create a funnel you should have a clear path to the conversion. If you can signup from any part of your site, maybe it's not a good idea to create a funnel. The same applies if your process has an external step (email) as Stephen suggested in the comments.